# Why is my count function only working on certain tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is an amateur question, but I've searched every resource I can think of, and now I'm at my wit's end. The following query works perfectly on most of my tables, but for some reason it is not working on the tables that I desperately need it for:

`SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM radio_r1_own_it
 WHERE daypart LIKE 'AM';`

The query works exactly how I want it to for nearly all of my tables, but for some reason it is returning a value of "0" on the tables I need it for (even though there are over 20 instances of "AM" in the "daypart" column on this table). I have checked and double-checked everything I can think of.

I'm relatively new to SQL but I've never encountered a problem like this before. Anyone have any ideas or resources that might help? Thanks so much for your time!

EDIT: I don't have enough reputation points to post a screen shot on here... but here's a link where you can see one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jUp.jpg

There are 29 columns in this table. If there's any other info that might help just let me know, thanks!

Comment: could you give us the structure and some sample data of that table?

Comment: Here's a link with a screen shot of the table: http://imgur.com/ZhyEqJY

Comment: Also, there are 29 columns in the table. Anything else you might want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM radio_r1_own_it WHERE daypart LIKE '%AM%';
```

If you want to order it using the count,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM radio_r1_own_it WHERE daypart LIKE '%AM%' ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

DESC - Descending order

ASC - Ascending order

Comment: For some reason it worked! I copied and pasted your exact query over my own and it came back with the result I was hoping for. I guess I must have had a typo in my query somewhere. THANK YOU so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the like part as shown below:

```
 where column_name like '%AM%'
```

when you write `like 'AM'` it is searching for the full match

Comment: "AM" is the exact match... but just in case I tried '%AM%' and I'm still returning 0 as the result. Thank you though!

Comment: As an alternative, since you probably have `AM` and `PM` as values, you can use a group by: `select count(*) from table_name group by daypart'

Answer (score 0):

LIKE statements are really slow in sql.  If you have a daypart column then I assume you have a date column.  I recommend something like this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM radio_r1_own_it
WHERE HOUR(dateColumn) < 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the string you're matching is exactly `AM` you need to use wildcard characters to match the string:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM radio_r1_own_it WHERE daypart LIKE '%AM%';
```

The `%` matches any number of characters before and after `AM`.

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for more information.